# Can my users mint their own NFT's ontop of my ERC1155 Token Contract?

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, nft, erc-1155

I am planning on incorporating ethereum tokens in my online music community. I wanted to know, if I wanted to allow artists to create their own nfts would they mint it on my erc155 token or would I need my own blockchain to do this?

or could I create a user interface where they deployed their own nfts but were able to exchange them on my platform?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want them to create their own NFT on "your" ERC-1155 token , you can. Actually, you create a contract that enable them to drop the Metadata, their address, pause and burn their asset, then mapping all of these.
But perhaps one contract for all of that is not enough:

- 1 contract to create the NFT
- 1 contract to deal with the NFTs of your community: see marketplace, DEX, etc...